# python carregar OCX

Tags: python

estou tentando utilizar uma ocx que "monitora" memoria de uma aplicação, em questao ela foi desenvolvida em VB, no VB está funcionando, mas precisaria migrar para Python.
ocx está registrada no windows: regsvr32 hookcontrol.ocx

```python
import win32com.client
# Define o VersionIndependentProgID baseado no TypeLib e na versão
version_independent_progid = "hookcontrol.ocx"
#erro também para o apontamento no registro
#version_independent_progid = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F1E2AAA6-E1B5-4648-9ED5-180ECE147792}\1.0\0\win32"

# Cria uma instância do controle ActiveX usando o VersionIndependentProgID
axHookControl = win32com.client.Dispatch(version_independent_progid)
```

erro reportado:

```
C:\Users\ricardo....\Downloads\exe>python ocxy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ricardo....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Cadeia de caracteres de classe inválida', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ricardo....\Downloads\exe\ocxy.py", line 8, in <module>
    axHookControl = win32com.client.Dispatch(version_independent_progid)
  File "C:\Users\ricardo....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 118, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\ricardo....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\ricardo....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Cadeia de caracteres de classe inválida', None, None)

arquivo: https://we.tl/t-vf2NDBIFwm?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05
```

Comment: Cadê o CLSID da classe COM que você quer instanciar? Não sei se está correto esse GUID comentado mas deveria ser algo assim `version_independent_progid = "F1E2AAA6-E1B5-4648-9ED5-180ECE147792"`

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta,    tanto o comentado ou se aplicado: version_independent_progid = "F1E2AAA6-E1B5-4648-9ED5-180ECE147792"   o erro é o mesmo: IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Cadeia de caracteres de classe inválida', None, None)

Comment: Você tem que abrir o aquivo `.idl` referente a biblioteca COM e procurara a definição da classe COM(COClass) lá o tem o CLSID correto. Faz muito tempo que não mexo com automação COM e não me recordo de como obter o idl

Comment: o ID informado estava ok, o problema era estar no w10 64bits, instalei um w7 32bits e python 32bits e a chamada deu certo.   obrigado Augusto pelo apoio

Comment: Tentou usar o modo de compatibilidade?

Comment: @AugustoVasques a princípio não deu certo em compatibilidade, mas deu bom usar no 32bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o ID informado estava ok, o problema era estar no w10 64bits, instalei um w7 32bits e python 32bits e a chamada deu certo